# Adding values_list produces AttributeError

Tags: python, django

When I do something like:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['sdnClearedDates'] = serializers.serialize('json', Profile.objects.filter(pk=object_id))
    return super(ProfileAdmin, self).change_view(
        request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
    )
```

it returns a valid list of json data. But when I add a `values_list('sdn_cleared_dates', flat=True)` inside the Profile query like this:

```
Profile.objects.values_list('sdn_cleared_dates', flat=True).filter(pk=object_id)
```

It returns an `AttributeError`.

```
Exception Value:    'list' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** added Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 616, in wrapper
  return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
  response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
  response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
  return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\*location*\admin.py", line 487, in change_view
  extra_context['sdnClearedDates'] = serializers.serialize('json', Profile.objects.values_list('sdn_cleared_dates', flat=True).filter(pk=object_id))
File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
  s.serialize(queryset, **options)
File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 94, in serialize
  concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model
```

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/crowdfunding/profile/9/change/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Can you share the traceback error? Besides what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AdeyemoToluwanimi added traceback. I just want the `sdn_cleared_dates` from my `Profile` model

Comment: values_list returns a tuple. Try `Profile.objects.values('sdn_cleared_dates').filter(pk=object_id)` as values() returns dictonaries which can be serialized.